# Bind to div position value in backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I would like to bind to a value like `$('#myDiv').position().top`

Every time this value changes I want to trigger an event. Is this possible, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin might be able to help you with this problem: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated

It's an interesting question and there might be a better solution out there!